# There is a scale with these notes?

Tags: notation, scales

C, D♭, F, G♭, A♭, B♮.

Does a scale using the notes above exist? Here is what is looks on a sheet:
[image]

Comment: If nowhere else, it exists in this question.

Comment: @TechnicGoblin5R, I don't understand your comment. If I think the scale C# major is hard to understand, how does this scale make easier to play piano?

Comment: This scale is  easy to understand if the base is B (not C). This scale in B has no sharps or flats, because the 6th note is always natural, independently of the base note (my comment above is incorrect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one Mr. Ian Ring has a whole [website](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/finder.php) devoted to the categorization and study of every possible scale. I suggest you check it out; it contains a veritable treasure trove of information on just about any scale you can imagine. From Ring's website, Zeitler called this scale "[Lycrimic](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/2403)". Of course, this scale is obscure enough that a search under that name pretty much only turns up websites devoted to listing all scales - you can call it whatever you want without fear of correction!

Comment: I was unable to determine why this scale got the name it did from Zeitler. I think it likely that Zeitler had a naming convention in mind, as several other scales he named are simply different by one letter down in the alphabet (ly**d**imic, ly**g**imic, ly**n**imic, etc.).